# junit test keep on getting stock infinitely on CompletedFuture.allof().join

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, completable-future

I am writing Junit test for a Class in which CompletableFuture is implemented but the test gets stuck infinitely on `CompletableFuture.allOf(future1,future2).join();`

My Class :

```
class Sample{
  @Autowired
  Executor executor;

  /* 
  piece of code
  */
  void SampleMethod(request){

    /*
    some piece of code
    */
    Obj1  response1 = someClass1.someMethod();
    CompletableFuture<Obj1> future1 = CompletableFuture.SupplyAsync(
      (Supplier<Obj1>) () -> {
      return someClass.someMethod(response1);
    },executor);

   
    Obj2 response2 = SomeClass2.someMethod();
    CompletableFuture<Obj2> future2 = CompletableFuture.SupplyAsync(
      (Supplier<Obj1>) () -> {
      return someClass.someMethod(response2);
    },executor);

    CompletableFuture.allOf(future1,future2).join();

}
```

I only have mocked Executor in my test class But the test is getting stucked on CompletableFuture.allof(future1, future2).join  because both of the future are not completed. Please suggest how to write the junit for this.

Comment: "*because both of the future are not completed*" So you need to figure out why that is, and you haven't given enough information about what `someClass.someMethod` does for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment above where you most likely have an issue in the someClass.someMethod(response1)
&
someClass.someMethod(response2)
But without more info on those it's hard to help. I would suggest mocking out those the someClass & someClass1 & someClass2 then putting this code in debug mode once you run the test to ensure the flow is making it into calling those mocks.

Also I would suggest not mocking your executor but instead use this in your test to create the executors: Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

I'm assuming both should help in your case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).